# Почему у меня не работает аннотация Inject ошибка Null Pointer

Tags: java, java-ee

У меня такой код:
Абстрактный класс `A` и наследник `B`. В другом классе я объявил 
`@Inject A a;`
Я захотел использовать этот экземпляр без слова `new`. То есть написал `a.method()`. Но происходит ошибка `Null Pointer Exeption`. Почему?

Оказалось надо поставить фреимворк Weld я использовал Maven

Вот код:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/servlet")
public class FirstServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    Student student;


    protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("s");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        student.hello();
        pw.println("<html>hi</html>");
        System.out.println("s");
    }

}

class Student {
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91291/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-).